# Unable to validate form which has dynamic rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-validate

I can't validate forms which have dynamic rows. When I click the button I add new rows. But these rows do not validate.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    //event.preventDefault();
    $v = $v+1;

    $("#zamowione_produkty").find('tbody')     
        .append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td class = "licz">'+$v+'</td>'))
            .append($('<td><input type="text" name ="nazwa[]" size="40" class="required" /></td>'))
            .append($('<td><input type="text" name ="warianty[]"  size="60" class="required" /></td>'))
            .append($('<td><input type="text" name ="ilosc[]"  size="10" class="required" onkeypress=validate(event) /></td>'))
            .append($('<td><input type="text" name="data[]"  size="15" class="data required"  /></td>'))
        );

    $('.data').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "pl" ] );
```

Zamowione_produkty is table in form2

To add validate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form2").validate();
});
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is the dynamic rows (http://jsfiddle.net/KJvLU/). I think the problem is that you have multiple `input`s with the same `name` attribute. `validate` interprets this as meaning that *any* input with that name can be filled out to meet the `required` rule. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by naming things the same way?

Comment: I add same name because next I use submit to send value to controller. If I use name[] I will have everyone value in table

Comment: I use same name because I don't know how I can send all to controller and get it them

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about how to use [jQuery's unobtrusive validation on dynamic content](http://www.jasoncavett.com/2011/03/using-unobtrusive-jquery-validation.html). You may want to check this out as a good starting point.

From that blog post, the important part is setting validation on new fields as they are added.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/TreeNode',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ajaxform').html(data);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#validation"));  // this is important
    }
});
```